# Run Configuration marked with an "X"

Tags: android, android-studio

What does the "X" mean in Android Studio? How can I resolve the error?

[image: image of error button in android studio]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can have various reasons.

The default run configuration for android is called **app**. It will just install and start your application.

If there is an error resolving the configuration, it will be displayed with a red "X".

To see what's wrong, you need to open the Dropdown and Select `Edit Configurations...` which will open up the settings. There the line leading to a fault is usually marked.

General reasons for the configuration not working include

- Problems syncing with gradle (Fix your dependencies), or
- Having problems finding your main / launcher activity, usually after renaming or deleting.

In some cases syncing or cleaning the project will resolve the error. But it is generally a good idea to look what error it is in the configuration settings, if you don't know what caused it.

Answer (score 0):

**FIRST** check you are trying to run the correct Build Variant. When I have this problem, it is usually because I am trying to run a release (signed) variant rather than debug.

[image]